# Mongoose getter function causes TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, compiler-errors

I'm encountering **TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent** error when running TypeScript compiler.

It looks like the problem is somehow related to the **id**'s getter function **idFromString**, because when I remove the **id** getter compiling doesn't fail.

The mongoose version in use is: 8.19.3

If somebody have an idea how to solve this, please share it :)

This is the part of the code that produces the error:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose"
import User, { UserId } from "../../../objects/user"

const schema = new Schema<User>({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        set: idToString,
        get: idFromString
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        set: toLowercase
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    code: {
        type: String
    },
    accountCreationDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: new Date()
    }
});

function idToString(value: UserId): string { 
    return value.uuidString()
}

function idFromString(value: string): UserId { 
    return new UserId(value)
}

function toLowercase(value: string): string { 
    return value.toLowerCase()
}

const UserModel = model<User>('User', schema);
export default UserModel
```

The error:

```
igordrljic@Igors-MacBook-Pro web-api % tsc
src/storage/mongoose/models/user.ts:4:16 - error TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.

const schema = new Schema<User>({
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    id: {
    ~~~~~~~~~
... 
    }
~~~~~
});
```

User object:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"
import Identifier from "../utility/identifier"
import { UserAccountStatus } from "./user-account-status"

export class UserId extends Identifier<User> { }

export default class User {

    constructor(
        readonly id: UserId,
        readonly email: string,
        readonly password: string,
        readonly status: UserAccountStatus = UserAccountStatus.pending,
        readonly code: string = uuidv4(),
        readonly accountCreationDate: Date = new Date()
    ) {
        this.id = id
        this.email = email
        this.password = password
        this.status = status
        this.code = code
        this.accountCreationDate = accountCreationDate
    }    
}
```

Identifier object:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"

export default class Identifier<Type> { 
    private value: string

    constructor(uuidString: string = uuidv4()) { 
        this.value = uuidString
    }
    
    uuidString(): string { 
        return this.value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same error some time ago and what I did to solve it was to create an interface and assign it as generic of the promise. In the interface I defined type, get and set properties to the Schema keys.

```
interface User{
   email: {
     type: string,
     set: any,
     get: any
   };
   firstName: {
     type: string,
     set: any,
     get: any
   };
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<User>({
  email: {
    type: String,
    get: getterFunction,
    set: setterFunction,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    get: getterFunction,
    set: setterFunction,
    required: true
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure if this workaround is optimal, but it worked for me. Hope it helps you as well.